# Blender Game Engine: A monitor for each camera?

Tags: python, game-engine, camera

I have a scene with two cameras and want to display every camera on a separate monitor in fullscreen. That means camera 1 is displayed on monitor 1 and camera 2 on monitor 2. How can I do this? Thanks for every answer!